# Player Accelerating Through the World (C++)

Tags: c++, position, controls

I am trying to make a platforming game in C++ using SDL2.  I want the player to accelerate/decelerate when walking or jumping/falling.  The problem is, because of the acceleration/deceleration the player often winds up wedged into blocks.  This is because if speed = 5 and player position x = 50 and the block is at x = 52 then the player will travel to player position x = 55 before realizing its in a block.  What can I do to fix this?

I know this is a weird and vague question, but I've been struggling with it for a while and don't have a clue as to the answer.  If anyone has a suggestion for what additional info would make this question better, feel free to let me know.

Comment: That's way too broad for a Stackoverflow question. We deal in *specific* code related problems here.

Comment: This *may* help: [Fix Your Timestep!](https://www.gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/). Also *maybe* this: [Pool Hall Lessons: Fast, Accurate Collision Detection Between Circles or Spheres](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131424/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php?print=1)

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing you can try is to check if the player will have hit the block before the player moves.